# Windows 10 pc suddenly incredibly laggy overnight - malware service executable - genuine?

Tags: windows-10, malware, lag

I have restarted my pc this morning and it is horribly laggy.  Previously I had absolutely no problems.  Now text doesn't appear directly on the screen, mouse movements are delayed and jumpy and applications are taking forever to open.

I have restarted a couple of times, removed programs from start up processes, deleted cookies, downloaded files, and started doing a windows defender scan.  Whilst looking at the task manager, I noticed that the antimalware was taking a lot of memory.  I restarted and its still there.  Is this normal?

[image]

I have tried to stop this process and I got a pop up saying access is denied.
[image]

I have worked my way through [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/window-10-random-lag-spike-after-restart-or-turn/a68b762e-780b-470c-88e4-c7e28554f809) and hasn't turned up anything

Spec is
My PC spec is plenty for any kind of usage.

CPU : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz
GPU : Nvidia GTX 1650
RAM : 16GB
Storage: C SSD 40 GB free, D HDD 590 GB free - not changed
OS : Windows 10 Home

Using CrystalDiskInfo , I looked at the reallocated sectors count and here it shows 0 for the HDD drive.
[image]

Checked my driver updates and the only thing that was updated yesterday was Defenders definitions which seems to happen everyday...

Comment: Antimalware always consumes ~250MB that is nothing unusual. A massively lagging PC without CPU usage often indicates a defect HDD. Check the SMART values of the HDD.

Comment: Thanks.  Running wmic diskdrive get status gave OK OK for each drive.. Running wmic /namespace:\\root\wmi path MSStorageDriver_FailurePredictStatus gave one value of predictfailure FALSE.  Changed directory to D and did this too, and also got a predict failure FALSE

Comment: IMHO those aggregated values are useless as they trigger too late. Use a SMART capable tool and directly look at the `Reallocated sectors count` RAW value. If is is higher than zero I would recommend to buy a new drive.

Comment: Updating the question to include this information.. It shows as 0.

Comment: Having run out of ideas, I shut the pc down and took it to a shop.  On opening, having been closed for 15 minutes, it magically works again like always.  No idea what it was.  It hadn't been on prior - it was switched off for 12 hours so not over heated.  I'm a bit concerned about what happened but its now back to working as it did so that*s a plus